# Wrapping generic types with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

**Problem**

I already have an Command handling framework and I'm trying to use Simple injector (3.3.2) to wrap my existing handlers in something Mediatr will understand. My commandhandlers always return a `CommandResult` so my handler interface only has `TCommand` as a Type variable whereas the handler interface Mediatr provides needs a `TResult` too.

So I have a `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` and Mediatr needs as `IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResult>`

**Thought about**

I could change my `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` to also implement `IRequestHandler<TCommand, CommandResult>` but then I'd have to change `ICommand<TCommand>` to implement `IRequest<TCommand, CommandResult>`. But I don't want to change existing code and have it coupled so tightly.

I can intercept the `ResolveUnregisteredType` on SimpleInjector and return whatever Mediatr needs (this will work). But then I need code that is dependent on *My Code* **AND** *Mediatr* **AND** *SimpleInjector* and I'd like to avoid that. *If all else fails, this would be my fallback scenario.*

**Tried**

I tried three ways to get the registrations to work, see the code

**Code**

It's a bit, at the top the tests where I expected at least one to pass. Then the interfaces I have now and a `TestCommand`. After that three regions with the stuff I tried.

**BTW**

I'm not putting the `Mediatr` tag on this question because it could apply to any framework.

```
using MediatR;
using NUnit.Framework;
using SimpleInjector;
using System;

namespace CommandHandlingTest
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Version_1()
        {
            var container = new Container();
            var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

            container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), assemblies);
            container.Register(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), assemblies);
            container.Verify();

            var commandBus = new MediatorCommandBus_1(container.GetInstance, container.GetAllInstances);

            var command = new TestCommand();

            Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => commandBus.Send(command));
            // Fails with Handler was not found for request of type CommandWrapped_1<TestCommand>
        }

        [Test]
        public void Version_2()
        {
            var container = new Container();
            var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

            container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), assemblies);
            container.Register(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), assemblies);
            container.Verify();

            var commandBus = new MediatorCommandBus_2(container.GetInstance, container.GetAllInstances);

            var command = new TestCommand();

            Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => commandBus.Send(command));
            // Fails with Handler was not found for request of type CommandWrapped_2<TestCommand, CommandResult>.
        }

        [Test]
        public void Version_3()
        {
            var container = new Container();
            var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

            container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), assemblies);
            container.Register(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), assemblies);
            container.Verify();

            var commandBus = new MediatorCommandBus_3(container.GetInstance, container.GetAllInstances);

            var command = new TestCommand();

            Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => commandBus.Send(command));
            // Fails with Handler was not found for request of type CommandWrapped_3<TestCommand, CommandResult>.
        }
    }

    /* Should not change */
    public interface ICommand { }


    /* Should not change */
    public interface ICommandBus
    {
        CommandResult Send<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand;
    }

    /* Should not change */
    public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand>
        where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        CommandResult Handle(TCommand command);
    }

    /* Should not change */
    public class TestCommand : ICommand { }

    /* Should not change */
    public class TestHandler : ICommandHandler<TestCommand>
    {
        public CommandResult Handle(TestCommand command)
        {
            return new CommandResult { IsValid = true };
        }
    }

    /* Should not change */
    public class CommandResult
    {
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    }

    #region Version 1
    public class MediatorCommandBus_1 : ICommandBus
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public MediatorCommandBus_1(SingleInstanceFactory singleInstanceFactory, MultiInstanceFactory multiInstanceFactory)
        {
            _mediator = new Mediator(singleInstanceFactory, multiInstanceFactory);
        }

        public CommandResult Send<TCommand>(TCommand command)
            where TCommand : ICommand
        {
            return _mediator.Send(new CommandWrapped_1<TCommand>(command)).Result;
        }
    }

    public class WrappedHandler_1<TCommand, TResult, TWrappedCommand> :
        IRequestHandler<TWrappedCommand, TResult>
        where TCommand : ICommand
        where TWrappedCommand : CommandWrapped_1<TCommand>, IRequest<TResult>
        where TResult : CommandResult
    {
        private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> _commandHandler;

        public WrappedHandler_1(ICommandHandler<TCommand> commandHandler)
        {
            _commandHandler = commandHandler;
        }

        public TResult Handle(TWrappedCommand message)
        {
            var handle = _commandHandler.Handle(message.UnWrap());
            return handle as TResult;
        }
    }

    public class CommandWrapped_1<TCommand> : IRequest<CommandResult>
        where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly TCommand _command;

        public CommandWrapped_1(TCommand command)
        {
            _command = command;
        }

        public TCommand UnWrap() => _command;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Version 2
    public class MediatorCommandBus_2 : ICommandBus
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public MediatorCommandBus_2(SingleInstanceFactory singleInstanceFactory, MultiInstanceFactory multiInstanceFactory)
        {
            _mediator = new Mediator(singleInstanceFactory, multiInstanceFactory);
        }

        public CommandResult Send<TCommand>(TCommand command)
            where TCommand : ICommand
        {
            return _mediator.Send(new CommandWrapped_2<TCommand, CommandResult>(command)).Result;
        }
    }

    public class WrappedHandler_2<TCommand, TResult> :
        IRequestHandler<CommandWrapped_2<TCommand, TResult>, TResult>
        where TCommand : ICommand
        where TResult : CommandResult
    {
        private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> _commandHandler;

        public WrappedHandler_2(ICommandHandler<TCommand> commandHandler)
        {
            _commandHandler = commandHandler;
        }

        public TResult Handle(CommandWrapped_2<TCommand, TResult> message)
        {
            var handle = _commandHandler.Handle(message.UnWrap());
            return handle as TResult;
        }
    }

    public class CommandWrapped_2<TCommand, TResult> : IRequest<TResult>
        where TCommand : ICommand
        where TResult : CommandResult
    {
        private readonly TCommand _command;

        public CommandWrapped_2(TCommand command)
        {
            _command = command;
        }

        public TCommand UnWrap() => _command;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Version 3
    public class MediatorCommandBus_3 : ICommandBus
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public MediatorCommandBus_3(SingleInstanceFactory singleInstanceFactory, MultiInstanceFactory multiInstanceFactory)
        {
            _mediator = new Mediator(singleInstanceFactory, multiInstanceFactory);
        }

        public CommandResult Send<TCommand>(TCommand command)
            where TCommand : ICommand
        {
            return _mediator.Send(new CommandWrapped_3<TCommand, CommandResult>(command)).Result;
        }
    }

    public class WrappedHandler_3<TCommand, TResult> :
        IRequestHandler<ICommandWrapped_3<TCommand, TResult>, TResult>
        where TCommand : ICommand
        where TResult : CommandResult
    {
        private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> _commandHandler;

        public WrappedHandler_3(ICommandHandler<TCommand> commandHandler)
        {
            _commandHandler = commandHandler;
        }

        public TResult Handle(ICommandWrapped_3<TCommand, TResult> message)
        {
            var handle = _commandHandler.Handle(message.UnWrap());
            return handle as TResult;
        }
    }

    public class CommandWrapped_3<TCommand, TResult> : ICommandWrapped_3<TCommand, TResult>
        where TCommand : ICommand
        where TResult : CommandResult
    {
        private readonly TCommand _command;

        public CommandWrapped_3(TCommand command)
        {
            _command = command;
        }

        public TCommand UnWrap() => _command;
    }

    public interface ICommandWrapped_3<out TCommand, out TResult> : IRequest<TResult>
        where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        TCommand UnWrap();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: What's missing from the question is an explanation why you are actually using MediatR. You already have your application-specific abstraction for handling commands; what's the use of having external (incompatible) interfaces as well?

Comment: Good question. The abstraction I have is the simplest that will work for me. MediatR is a widely used library so that's what I chose to use first. I'm not sure if there's another option that will be used in the final solution, but comparable problems are likely to arise with another implementation.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the actual *only* problem you are having here is mapping from MediatR to you own interface and back. Removing MediatR from the equation solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, but I'd have to replace it with another implementation. And I don't want to write that myself. Maybe I'll be using a remote bus or interprocess communication. Either way, the problems *might* be the same. Also I'm curious how to solve this and why it doesn't work.

Comment: What problem does MediatR solve for you?

Comment: It's a simple implementation of a commandbus. As I stated in the question there is a solution I can use, but that is not ideal in my opinion. So the question is not as much about MediatR as it is about why the registration and resolving in SimpleInjector doesn't work as I expect it to. Tomorrow I'll edit the question to make that clearer, now it's time for bed ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133236/discussion-between-john-landheer-and-steven).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the followihng line:

```
container.Register(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), assemblies);
```

With:

```
container.Register(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), typeof(WrappedHandler_2<,>));
```

The batch-registration overload of `Register` that takes in a list of assemblies, skips generic registrations by default (unless you specify otherwise), since generic types often need special handling. In your case you are actually not interested in batch-registering, since you only have one mapping that has your interest (which is the wrapped handler).